# Security Researchers: How do you choose what services or software you are going to audit next?

Tags: penetration-test, exploit, audit

Security Researchers: How do you choose what services or software you are going to audit next?

I am referring to finding vulnerabilities and developing exploits in various applications. I am wandering how decide what software you will target next?

Comment: +3 for this awesome question!  A simple +1 won't cut it.

Answer (score 6):

I audit a lot of code, [I write exploits](http://www.exploit-db.com/author/?a=628),  and I have accumulated more than 50 CVE's over the course of about 6 years of bug hunting.

When I went on my first serious bug hunt I was looking for weak projects that had not be extensively audited by [the community](http://www.exploit-db.com)(or milw0rm back in the day).  To do this I used [SourceForge's Advanced Search](http://sourceforge.net/directory/developmentstatus:4-beta/language%3aphp/freshness%3arecently-updated/?q=php&sort=popular),  which has changed a lot.  Basically I was looking for a PHP project that people where downloading and using,  but wasn't very popular.  Lets say around ~1,000 downloads and less than 1 year old.  I found Ultimate PHP Board which turned out to be [very insecure](http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/1932/).

As time progressed I got bored with insecure projects so I changed my tactics entirely and started going after popular projects.  For example [I exploit PHPMyAdmin](http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/7382/) which is the most downloaded PHP application.

After years of penetration testing and application development you get a kind of 6th sense into how the code works and where the problem areas can be.  You can look at a piece of functionality and write an implementation in your head and pick out where things could go wrong.  So on a penetration test I always ask my self the same question: "**What is the worst that could happen?**". And then go out and focus my testing based on this question.

I'll give you a good example. I saw an advertizement for [Canonical Landscape](http://www.canonical.com/enterprise-services/ubuntu-advantage/landscape) (Maker of Ubuntu).  In the ad it showed a feature of Landscape where you could **execute a command on every machine you own as root**.  I thought to my self,  "What if it was vulnerable to CSRF?".  I signed up for a free trail,  and sure enough,  you could gain remote root on **every machine** using a single forged HTTP request.  Outch!  (I also got [remote root on cPanel with CSRF](http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/584089), and I earned a severity metric :)

Another flaw I found in Google Music, I uploaded an MP3 that had JavaScript in all of the ID3 tags.  Sure enough the artist and album names where being printed to the page,  and I got $500 from the bug bounty program with my very first test.  One of the reasons why I chose this input is because i knew it wouldn't be exercised by a dumb vulnerability scanner.  Its as if I knew it would fail ahead of time. That kind of innate understanding only comes with years of practice.

Comment: Link http://www.exploit-db.com/author/1/?a=628 is no longer accessible. Returns 404.

Comment: @kinunt  http://www.exploit-db.com/author/?a=628 ?

Answer (score 1):

By scanning the internet, the Nmap team has [elaborated a list of the most commonly exposed TCP and UDP services](http://danielmiessler.com/blog/a-summary-of-new-nmap-features-from-blackhatdefcon-2008). You can make use of this list in order to determine the next service you will be auditing next, assuming that you want to target the most commonly used ones.